# jquery page splitter height to fit the user screen

Tags: jquery, plugins, dynamic, height, splitter

i am using a jquery page-splitter plugin in an asp.net application, 
from here: http://methvin.com/splitter/

the structure of my page is as follows:

// div1 holds the page header
 

 
    // div 2 holds some page content
 

 
   // div 3 - this holds the page splitter

The splitter plugin requires me to specify a static height and this creates problems 
when the screen size varies.

I want to be able to set the page splitter height exactly in pixels so that it fits
any screen size and does not overflow creating vertical scroll bars in the page.
Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the document size using $(document).height(), or the window size using $(window).height().

From there you can set the size of the splitter div when the page loads using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(

    function() {

        $("#splitterID").css("height", $(document).height() + "px");


                })
```

If you post an example of the code you're using we might be able to sort out another solution if the above doesn't work for you.